# Are fae ephemeral and or supernal entities in Mage 2E?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, changeling-the-lost, mage-the-awakening-2e

Fae are mentioned in the section on ephemeral entities in the new Chronicles of Darkness book Mage: the Awakening.

> ## Bans & Banes
>
> All ephemeral and Supernal entities suffer from a mystical compulsion known as a ban, a behavior that the being must or must not perform under certain conditions. Bans increase in both complexity and consequences with Rank.
>
> **Rank 1**  entities have mild bans that are easily triggered but don’t endanger the being. A spirit of bliss can’t resist an offering of opiates; *a weak Fae must play any game of chance that it is invited to.*
>   M:tA pg 255

Prior to this they only ephemeral or  supernal entities mentioned are ghosts,  spirits, goetia and entities from each of the 5 supernal realms.

Fae are mentioned in Changeling: the lost as inscrutable Lords and Ladies,  not summonable creatures.

What are the fae mentioned here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Fae" in this context are beings from the Supernal Realm called Arcadia where Acanthus Awaken, rather than the other place called Arcadia where Changelings are taken and escape from. The Mage core book makes no reference to the Changeling!Arcadia or Changeling!Fae, so the fae mentioned in the ephemeral being rules must refer to the Mage!Fae from Mage!Arcadia. The developer [has talked about this distinction.](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-new-world-of-darkness/changeling-the-lost/805704-meet-the-huntsmen?p=813206#post813206)

> Yeah, Changeling's Arcadia is not Mage Arcadia; the Fae Acanthus mages summon and deal with are not the Gentry, just like the Beasts Thyrsus summon aren't Begotten, and the Demons Mastigos summon aren't Unchained. Changeling was the only game that teased such a connection (absent throwaway bits of Geist, which are also being chucked) and I'm cutting it off.

*David Brookshaw*

Answer (score 4):

"Fae" here is the generic term for the denizens of the Supernal Realm of Arcadia, which may or may not be the same place that changelings spend their Durance. Just as Pandemonium is full of "demons" which are not the Unchained of *Demon: the Descent*, these fae come in all shapes and sizes and are not necessarily tied to the setting of *Lost*.

Comment: I've just reread the section on supernal summoning and it calls the supernal entities  you summon from Arcadia 'fae'. It also calls entities from pandemonium 'beasts'. I could edit that in if you like.

Comment: While everything I've read leaves it a little ambiguous as to whether the Supernal Realm of Arcadia and the Arcadia the Changelings visit are the same, the materials seem to strongly imply that they are not the same. ATayloe's answer goes further and suggests that outside the core books developer commentary provides a firm "No", which accords with what is in the books.

Answer (score 1):

**My Best Bet:** If by 'Fae' from 'Changeling: The Lost' you are talking about The True Fae, remember that they often have entire courts or realms dedicated to them, filled with followers, creations, goblins, faerie beasts, changelings (captured and/or willing) and other beings touched by or created from their glamour or the substance of their realm... Such creatures will frequently exhibit traits of, (or that are expected by) their master. The commonality of such traits means that were a Mage to summon some of them, there is little to prevent him mistakenly continuing to assume that these Fae beings must have a similar grouping of nature and hierarchy as other types of spirits do... After all, beings taken from the same Lord's realm will have certain commonalities in appearance, abilities and temperament depending on their Lord. As Terry Pratchett once wrote "If it comes through the door marked whatsit, it's gonna get treated like a whatsit." And of course... the only way i can imagine for this misassumption to get truly corrected would involve managing to successfully summon a True Fae Lord (unlikely), realize the bindings that worked on their creations didn't bind them (VERY likely) and then survive the clumsy attempt at binding a True Fae Lord (sounds dangerously unlikely, even for an Archmage.